Correctly determine additional distance covered due to universe expansion
Say a new photon now is emitted from one of the stars in the Tucana Dwarf galaxy. Question,- what is an exact additional distance covered in the percentages (relative to the current distance from us) until this new photon will reach our Solar system ?
Let's assume that photon is directly emitted in the line of sight towards Earth. For the greatly simplifying the task, Hubble constant dependance on time $H(t)$ can be ignored and current value $H_0$ can be used instead. (Although if calculations are simple enough, this constancy can be rejected).
Note: It's not a home-work, I raised this question/problem myself just from curiosity.
My naive approach.
Present day Hubble law states that $$v=H_0D \tag 1$$
Multiplying each equation side by time elapsed $t$ we get additional distance expanded in specific time frame:
$$ \tag 2 vt=\Delta D = H_0Dt $$
Dividing by $D$ each side and acknowledging to the first order of approximation that time needed for a photon to reach us is about $D/c$, we arrive to additional distance covered in percentages, based on current galaxy distance from us :
$$\tag 3 100\times \frac {\Delta D}{D} = \frac {H_0 D}{c} ,$$
So if such new photon is now emitted from Tucana Dwarf galaxy,- upon reaching us it will cover $\large \approx 100×\frac {70 (km/s)/Mpc × 3.2 Mly}{c} = 0.023\%$ additional distance (or $736~ly$) due to universe expansion.
The main problem with my approach is that additional distance covered to us is not constant and depends on time $\Delta D=\Delta D(t)$ in some non-linear way, because as photon progresses towards us,- new space parcels are constantly added and so total additional distance covered must follow some sort of exponential or power law.
This feels like we need some sort of integration procedure to correctly accumulate the ratio of additional distance covered. But I have no slightest idea how to do that. Any help/ proposals ?

You know the velocity of the photon $c$, the initial distance $X$, and the Hubble parameter $H$ measured in meters per second of apparent recession per meter of distance.
Actually integrating the real thing here would in fact be difficult; we should be able to integrate a simpler expression by imagining that instead of the receiver receding from the emitter the photon just slows down the same amount (this should give the same result, since velocity is relative - yes I know it’s improper but it’s functionally the same from a mathematical standpoint). We will note that this appears to be the case when, as the receiver recedes, the photon’s relative velocity to the receiver decreases in the frame of the emitter even though it always travels at $c$.
Imagine the photon is emitted at $t=0$ and has a position $\mathrm{d}x=(c-H(X-x))\mathrm{d}t$. Here, $H(X-x)$ is the Hubble parameter times the remaining distance between the photon and the receiver. We write $c-H(X-x)$ because in our emitter’s frame the relative velocity between the photon (which we observe to move at $c$, as expected) and the receiver (moving away at $H(X-x)$.
Given that the relative velocity of the photon is $\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\mathrm{d}t}=c-H(X-x)$ we can invert that expression to obtain $\frac{\mathrm{d}t}{\mathrm{d}x}=\frac{1}{c-H(X-x)}$, the time it takes to travel a certain distance. This will be key.
We could just multiply by $\mathrm{d}x=X$ for when the photon has travelled the whole distance, but because of the dependency of $\frac{\mathrm{d}t}{\mathrm{d}x}$ on $x$ we have to integrate. The expression is (or at least should be, if I’m not totally off my rocker)
$$\mathrm{d}t=\int_0^X\frac{\mathrm{d}t}{\mathrm{d}x}\mathrm{d}x=\int_0^X \frac{1}{c-H(X-x)} \mathrm{d}x.$$
This at least produces the correct result for $H=0$; this makes the integrand constant which in turn yields $\mathrm{d}t=\frac{X}{c}$ as one would expect.
For $H\neq0$:

I plotted the integral in Desmos with the $x$-axis being $X$ (coordinate distance away at emission) and the $y$-axis being $\mathrm{d}t$ (the time required for the photon to hit the receiver); this graph in particular sets $c=1$ and $H=0.1$. Maybe in a surprise, our model works: for values $X\ll \frac{c}{H}$, the graph says that the time required accounting for expansion (red) is about equal to the time required not accounting for it (blue), and the required time diverges to infinity as the distance approaches a finite limit equal to $\frac{c}{H}=10$ in our case. This value is the familiar horizon of the observable Universe, outside of which objects are receding apparently faster-than-light and will thus never be reached by photons traveling at mere lightspeed.
Now that you know the elapsed time, simply multiply by $c$ to obtain the total distance covered in the emitter frame, and divide by the original distance $X$ if you want to get a ratio $R$. It’d look like
$$R=\frac{c}{X} \int_0^X \frac{1}{c-H(X-x)} \mathrm{d}x.$$
I can’t simplify that integral at the moment (not at my computer right now), but it appears to behave as expected. I hope it works for whatever application you need!

Wolfram Alpha reduced this time integral to $$\ln\left(\frac {c}{c - H L}\right)/H$$. Multiplying it by $c/L$ and substituting all values for mentioned galaxy,- $c×\ln(c/(c − 70(km/s)/Mpc ×3.2Mly))/(3.2Mly×70(km/s)/Mpc)$ I get that true additional covered distance percentage is about $100.011%$ or total distance covered will be $\approx 6.4Mly$. As long as it is within cosmological horizon $c/H$- it's OK. Btw, my naive approach is truly naive, because it is off by at least 4 orders of magnitude :-)

Yeah, travel time it’s important ;) Glad Wolfram could help out too.
